# Rails server - "/home/bck/mine/config/initializers/load_app_config.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to start rails server but it is leading to above mentioned error. 
Can anyone tell me what is this error means and why it happened and how to overcome from this?

Here is the full stack trace

```
/home/bck/mine/config/initializers/load_app_config.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/bck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/bck/mine/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/bck/mine/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/bck/mine/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/bck/mine/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /home/bck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This is my load_app_config.rb

```
raw_config = File.read(Rails.root.to_s + "/config/app_config.yml")
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
APP_CONFIG.each {|k,v| v.symbolize_keys! if v.respond_to?('keys')}
```

This is my environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
OnlineStoreLocator::Application.initialize!
```

This is my app_config.yml

```
development:
  domain: localhost:3000
  dbhost: localhost
  dbuser: root
  dbpwd: root
  databases:
    new_users: new_users
    old_users: old_users

test:
  domain: example.com
  dbhost: localhost
  dbuser: root
  dbpwd: root
  algo_tobe_used: leven
  analytics: 'no'
  ad: 'ad'
  staging: 'staging'

staging:
  domain: example.com
  dbhost: localhost
  dbuser: root
  dbpwd: root
  algo_tobe_used: leven
  analytics: analytics
  staging: 'staging'
  databases:
    new_users: new_users
    old_users: old_users

production:
  domain: api.demo.in
  dbhost: 123.123.123.123
  dbuser: xyz
  dbpwd: xyz
  algo_tobe_used: leven
  staging: 'no'
  databases:
    new_users: new_users
    old_users: old_users
```

I am using Rails 4.0.1
ruby 2.0.0

Comment: The issue is, it's unable to find YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env]. 
This value comes to be nil

Comment: Make sure the path to your config file is correct. BTW what environment you try to run server on?

Comment: @Ajay both environment and load_app_config.rb are auto generated right?

Comment: environment.rb -autogenerated but load_app_config.rb is your custom file.

Comment: Load_app_config.rb is same like my other projects.